# How to randomly pick a set number of items from a string, space delimited?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-4

Given a string like below:

```
string = "hotdog cat food pickle sock ring lock fist door"
```

What would be the right way to randomly pick 4 items (separated by space). So that I can return:

```
result = "fist_sock_food_cat"
```

Comment: did you get this one working? :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I did! Sorry about the delay :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use  [String#`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-split) and [Array#`sample`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sample):

```
string
  .split     #=> ["hotdog", "cat", "food", "pickle", "sock", "ring", "lock", "fist", "door"]
  .sample(4) #=> ["ring", "pickle", "food", "fist"]
  .join('_') #=> "ring_pickle_food_fist"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use shuffle:

```
result = string.split.shuffle.first(4).join("_")
```